# Tie Stack Overflow account with Server Fault?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, serverfault, google-openid

I used my Gmail login to provide an open ID on Stack Overflow, then when I did the same on Server Fault I expected it to use the same username and whatnot, but on Server Fault I am now "unknown(google)". Is there a way to tie the accounts together?

Comment: That's the problem with GMail/Google OpenID

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go edit your profile on ServerFault, then add the account in the accounts tab in your profile.

Comment: How?  Where is the add account?  I see 3 related accounts, and a clear all associations, but I want to associate the meta stackexchange account, and I don't see any way to do that.

Comment: Stack Exchange stuff will not associate with StackOverflow stuff, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36/will-there-be-account-association-between-se-or-meta-se-and-the-so-family-sites/.  (Of course I've seen that you've been there, I put up the link for others to come).